# How to change Laravel's default broadcast auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast, laravel-5.6, pusher

So, as my title says, I want to change Laravel's default `Broadcast` auth middleware to a custom auth middleware that I made which uses token-based authentication. I made this because my app is an API-based app, and, when a user authenticates, I create a session token and send it to him and also store it inside the DB with an `expires_at` column.
I am using `Pusher`.

I have the following middleware:

```
class AuthCustom
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // if we have the session token stored in header
        if ($request->header('x-session')) {
            $session = Session::where('id', $request->header('x-session'))->where('expires_on', '>=', date('Y-m-d G:i:s'))->with('user')->first();
            if ($session !== null) {
                $user = (new User())->where('id', $session->user_id)->first();
                if ($user !== null) {
                    $request->merge(['user' => $user]);

                    return $next($request);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

My `BroadcastServiceProvider` code is as follows:

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

If I put `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'authcustom']);` in `BroadcastServiceProvider`, the `boradcasting/auth` gives a `403` status code because `$request->user()` is null, which then results in an `Access forbidden`.

I have tried searching the whole damn web, and I found nothing about changing the default auth middleware for broadcasting.

I even tried removing `Broadcast::routes()` and customizing a new route `/broadcast` which returned a `Pusher` `socket_auth` object and everytime I got a `419 Unkown` status code.

Any ideas or maybe you can point me in the direction where I could manage this?
Thank you!

Later edit:
My JS Echo connection looks like this:

```
Vue.use(VueEcho, {
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cluster: 'eu',
    authEndpoint: 'http://localhost/api.easycargo.ro/public/broadcasting/auth',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'x-session': this.auth.token
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably not the problem: Just pointing out `date('Y-m-d G:i:s')` This is the first time I see someone using `G` instead of `H` I'm not sure if MySQL (or any DB) can return the date correctly.

Comment: @cbaconnier don't worry about that, it works just the way it is

Comment: You could've used laravel passport. It's the default for laravel's API authentication. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

Comment: @SjoerddeWit hmm, good point, had not idea about that Laravel feature. Thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm glad you got something working. For later readers, here's a more Laravel-esque way to solve the problem in the question: create a [custom auth guard](https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#adding-custom-guards) used to authenticate requests for the special routes.

Laravel's `AuthManager` includes a helper method—`viaRequest()`—that simplifies the creation of a `Guard` that authenticates a user with data from the request context without the need to fully-implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard`. We can bind our custom guard in the `boot()` method in *AuthServiceProvider.php*:

```php
public function boot()
{
    Auth::viaRequest('custom-auth', function ($request) {
        // Any custom user-lookup logic here. For example:
        if ($request->header('x-session')) {
            $user = // ...try to fetch a user...
            return $user;
        }
    });
}
```

As we can see, we just pass a closure to the `viaRequest()` method that returns a `User` object when authentication succeeds, or `null` when authentication fails.

Next, we'll tell Laravel about our new auth guard by adding an entry to the `'guards'` array in *config/auth.php*:

```php
'guards' => [ 
    ...
    'broadcasting' => [
        'driver' => 'custom-auth', 
    ],
],
```

Finally, we need to update the middleware for any routes that should authenticate a user with our custom `Guard`. We can use Laravel's built-in auth middleware and specify which guard to apply as a [middleware parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/middleware#middleware-parameters). For example, we'll initialize the broadcasting routes in the question's *BroadcastServiceProvider.php*:

```php
Broadcast::routes([ 'middleware' => [ 'auth:broadcasting', ... ] ]);
```

...where `broadcasting` matches the name we assigned to our custom `Guard` in *config/auth.php*.

This approach enables us to use all of Laravel's `Auth` services, provides a more central place to define our authentication logic, and simplifes automated testing because we can more easily mock up authentication as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach, I learned something new today. I'll give you the bounty points in 30 minutes.

Comment: @southpaw93 You're welcome! [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/passport) may also help out with this kind of API auth stuff. You can leave the bounty up for a while if you like--someone may have a better idea than mine. I always like to see the alternatives.

Comment: The `Broadcast::routes([ 'middleware' => [ 'auth:broadcasting', ... ] ]);` saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

I actually managed to find a solution, so all I needed to do was bind the `$user` that I got in my custom `auth` middleware to the request by doing the following thing:

```
$request->merge(['user' => $user]);

//add this
$request->setUserResolver(function () use ($user) {
   return $user;
});
```

and now `$request->user()` which laravel checks returns the user object and passes the validation.